# Store Auto Generated Username into Database DJango

Tags: python, html, django, forms, authentication

I am creating a registration form that accepts the end-user's Firstname, Lastname, email, and password.  the program is designed to auto-generate a username.  I have created a function that auto generates a unique username; however, I am new to Django and unsure how to get my auto-generated username to store into the database along with the user's info.  Currently, the program is storing the user's manually input info.

Comment: What database are you using? Please add that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned you receive users' first_name, last_name and email you can try to create a username in many different ways with your obtained values.

such as, if you want to create user with their first name then,
firstly check if any user exists with that name. Sometimes users input two or three words in their first name then you can combine it and check if that username exists. If not exists, set that as a username.

As you receive an email you can separate it into two or three parts for example `abc@gmail.com`.Separate domain name and take the rest of the part and check if that name exists.

if you don't find any unique username then add some extra letter or number until getting the unique username.

```
username = instance.email.split("@")[0]
        counter = 1
        while User.objects.filter(username=username):
            username = instance.first_name + str(counter)
            counter += 1
```

I Hope, you have got the idea.

Comment: Should I implement this function in views.py or forms.py?

Comment: @Amz in views or models